# Help with finding solution of an equality

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

I am stuck at finding solutions for solving this equality:
so i need to find
 $$n\in\mathbb{N}$$

For this:

$$ 1547\Phi(n) = 768n$$

So $\Phi (n)$ is Euler's function
 I know how it is defined and everything
But i am stuck at how to solve that equation.
My idea is to use modules and something
But i am stuck
Any help would be appreciated. Both hints and longer answers.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: 768 and 1547 have no divisors in common, so 1547 must divide $n$. Probably the first or second multiple you try will work :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If we bring the constants to the RHS and consider their prime factorizations, then

$$\begin{align}\varphi(n) &= n\cdot\frac{2^8\cdot3}{7\cdot13\cdot17}\\
&= n \cdot \frac{6\cdot8\cdot 16}{7\cdot13\cdot17}\\
&= n \cdot \frac{6}{7}\cdot\frac{16}{17}\cdot \frac{8}{13}\cdot\frac{3}{3}\\
&= n \cdot \frac{6}{7}\cdot\frac{16}{17}\cdot \frac{12}{13}\cdot\frac{2}{3} \\
&= n \cdot \frac{7-1}{7}\cdot\frac{17-1}{17}\cdot \frac{13-1}{13}\cdot\frac{3-1}{3} \end{align}$$

Now, recall that [Euler's Product Formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function#Euler.27s_product_formula) says that

$$\varphi(n) =n \prod_{p\mid n} \frac{p - 1}{p}$$

where $p$ are the distinct primes that divide $n$.

By direct comparison, we can say that integers $n$ with distinct prime factors $3, 7, 13, 17$ are solutions to the equation; that is,

$$n = 3^a7^b13^c17^d$$

for all $a, b, c, d\in \mathbb{Z}^+$ all satisfy the equation - although they are not necessarily the only ones.

Comment: (+1) I would say they are the only ones, if we assume that a prime number among $\{3,7,13,17\}$ does not divide $n$ then $\frac{\varphi(n)}{n}$ cannot be $\frac{768}{1547}$. Am I wrong?

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio That is correct. However, I suspect that it may somehow be possible to introduce unit multipliers (just like I did for $\frac{3}{3}$) so that the RHS of the manipulated equality gives a form similar to that of Euler's formula - though, I also presume there is a way to prove/disprove such a possibility.

Comment: I bet there is just to notice that the product of numbers of the form $\left(1-\frac{1}{p}\right)$ cannot be $1$, it has to be less than one.